# Call a function argument stored in a list

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, drc

I need to test a suite of argument conditions in order to find the best model (using the `drc` package). That is, I'd like to store function arguments in a list and then call them into the `drm()` function. The `drc` package has a function (`mselect()`) to do this, but it has been known to fail for unknown reasons (https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/a1bu44/any_idea_what_im_doing_wrong_with_the_mselect/).

---

**Example Data**

```
library(drc) # This also loads in the S.alba data
data(S.alba)

head(S.alba)
  Dose  Herbicide DryMatter
1    0 Glyphosate       4.7
2    0 Glyphosate       4.6
3    0 Glyphosate       4.1
4    0 Glyphosate       4.4
5    0 Glyphosate       3.2
6    0 Glyphosate       3.0
```

---

**Failed Attempt**

```
# List of function arguments to be assessed e.g. drm(...fct = W1.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA)
model_list <- list(curve = c(W1.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA)),
                             LL.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA))))

# Failed function, attempting to return a list of results
model_select <- function(data, mlist){
    model =  data %>%
        drm(DryMatter ~ Dose, Herbicide, data = . , fct = mlist)
    metric = AIC(model)
    return(metric)
}
model_select(data = S.alba, mlist = model_list)
```

> Error in drm(DryMatter ~ Dose, Herbicide, data = ., fct = mlist) : 
>     First entry in list to 'fct' NOT a function

**Semi-Working Attempt**

```
model_select_2 <- function(data){
    model =  data %>%
        drm(DryMatter ~ Dose, Herbicide, data = . , fct = W1.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA)))
    metric = AIC(model)
    return(metric)
}
model_select_2(data = S.alba)

model_select_2(data = S.alba)
[1] 106.9226
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
model_select(data = S.alba, mlist = model_list)
[1] W1.4-106.9226
[2] LL.4-99.54702
```

Comment: Sorry, the last code block should just be the desired output from the function `model_select()`

Comment: Hey @akrun, I forgot to add the "curve" names to the desired output. Probably a regex then `paste0()` but not sure!

Comment: It is a list of one element.  So if you do `fct = mlist[[1]]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is how you are creating `model_list`. You want to combine those values with `list()` rather than `c()`. The latter tried to combine them into the same object.

The next thing you can do is `sapply` over the list of curves to get the result for each input. A working example would be

```
model_list <- list(curve = list(W1.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA)),
                             LL.4(fixed = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA))))
model_select <- function(data, mlist){
   sapply(mlist$curve, function(curve){
      model <- drm(DryMatter ~ Dose, Herbicide, data = data , fct = curve)
      metric = AIC(model)
   })
}
model_select(data = S.alba, mlist = model_list)
# [1] 106.92259  99.54702
```

Comment: Ahhhh! I've never would've thought to make a list of lists...would it be possible to add the curve names to the results so I would know which model is best? (See updated "Desired Output")

Comment: Well, it's not super easy unless you name the elements in your sub-list. It's kind of messy to guess the names from function calls otherwise. Then you could paste that data in to the result if you like.